# Coldfusion how to find component mapping

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, railo, cfc, application.cfc

My Directory structure

- Component files     - `c:\inetpub\webroot\{project_A}\cfcs\lib`
- web-files           - `c:\inetpub\webroot\{project_A}\sub_folder\`
- Config Files        - `c:\inetpub\environment_config\{Project_A_XML}`
- Sub-folder component directory Mapping in [sub_folder/Application.cfc]  -         `<cfset this.mappings["/com"] = "#environment_config_xml.rootProjectDir#com/cfc/lib/" />`

In environment_config_xml, holding project absolute root path.
application.cfc reading environment_config_xml and fetching all environment variables in application scope.

when creating object in sub-folder ERROR:

`Could not find the ColdFusion component or interface com.Utils. 
Ensure that the name is correct and that the component or interface exists.`

- How can i fix this issue ?
- Is there way i can't find out what mapping path is coming ?
- Any  variable which i can dump and find out, what application.cfc mapping?

Comment: `getApplicationMetaData()` returns a struct called `mappings`, introduced with ColdFusion 10.

Comment: i have coldfusion 9 it doesn't seems to be working....

Comment: The developer version of Adobe CF 11 is free. Railo is even freer. Try the `getApplicationMetaData()` approach on you local computer

Comment: *it doesn't seems to be working* As they said it was introduced in CF10. It obviously cannot work in CF9, because that function did not exist yet when it was released. Though that raises the question, why tag the question "Railo" if you are using CF9?